# Populating a textview after spinner item selection (C#, Xamarin, Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin, spinner

I understand this is a very basic question, but I cannot seem to overcome it with my limited C#/Android app capabilities.

EDIT: In summary, I have a method that's called when a spinner item is selected. In that method I get a bunch of text via a database call. I'd like to be able to access that list of text in my OnCreate so I can use it to populate textviews (among other things)

In my code I have a user select a value from a spinner. When they select it, I launch a bit of code that uses the spinner selection to query a SQL database and split into a string array called dataList shown below:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        //Not showing you lots of stuff, because its irrelevant
        Spinner RiderSelectSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.RiderSelectSpinner);
        TextView FCompStock = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.FCompStock);

        RiderSelectSpinner.ItemSelected += rider_Selected;
    }

        public void rider_Selected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
        //Not showing you many database things because its not relevant

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataString))
        {
            string[] dataList = dataString.Split(',');
        }
        }
```

Here's the kicker, and my question. I want to display certain values of my dataList as a textview defined in OnCreate. My text views (of course) have no context down here in my rider_Selected method. Essentially, I wanted to put the following just after I define dataList above:

```
FCompStock.Text = dataList[0];
```

I've tried to formulate solutions by defining dataList in the main activity, thereby having it available to onCreate and my method here, but I would need an event to trigger populating the textview. I also tried simply formulating the method allowing me to pass dataList back to where its called, but no dice there either.

Could someone please guide me on either how to pass dataList back to the original call, or possibly how to create an event to populate the text view?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if this is what you want. But you can access your TextView or any other element in Activity by Id. For example: TextView t = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1); and then change the value: t.Text = "New value". Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself very well. I want to assign my textvew some text, but the text is generated in another method. That other method is a spinner.itemselected. Somehow I need to make my spinner.itemselected method return this text.

Comment: and why can't you access the textView in that method and set it? Is that method in some other object than Activity one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can declare your TextView outside the onCreate method as global.

```
TextView FCompStock;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    //Not showing you lots of stuff, because its irrelevant
    Spinner RiderSelectSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.RiderSelectSpinner);
    FCompStock = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.FCompStock);

    RiderSelectSpinner.ItemSelected += rider_Selected;
}

public void rider_Selected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
    //Not showing you many database things because its not relevant

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataString))
    {
        string[] dataList = dataString.Split(',');
        FCompStock.Text = "Whatever you want";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You know, I had tried this, but I used the whole statement assigning the resource ID, which didn't work. It didn't occur to me to separate the two.

Comment: Ok. You need to set your content view before you can use findViewById.